# Show React component as popup using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am pretty new with React and Typescript and trying to render the following component on the the click of a button

```
const MyComponent = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <HeaderCell>Attribute</HeaderCell>
              <HeaderCell>Value</HeaderCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <DataCell>A</DataCell>
              <DataCell>B</DataCell>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
};
```

I would like the component to appear as a pop up on click of a button but I don´t know how to do that using Typescript and need help.

```
<Button onClick={() => MyComponent }>Click</Button>
```

I would appreciate if you could help me with my problem.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. By "pop up" do you mean as a dialog or modal? Or do you mean it's only visible after the click? Either way the normal approach is to set a value in state indicating if it's visible or not, and render based on that. If you mean "pop up" as in dialog/modal most libraries will have a "visible" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use state to set the popup visible at the click of the button.

In your component create a piece of state

```
const MyConponent = () => {

  //....
 
  const [popupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState<boolean>(false)

  //....

   function togglePopup() {
     setPopupVisible(!popupVisible)
   }

  //....

}


//In the button, add the function 

<Button onClick={togglePopup}>Click</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gabriel. If my button is outside `MyComponent`, how will I access the state and the function in `onClick`?

Comment: @Lara By passing the function as a property, as with any other lifted state.

Comment: @Lara, if it helped you, please upvote the question and accept it :) , I would be really grateful.